# Showing data from 2 tables with php mysqli; doesn't show anything

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem when showing data from 2 tables; pegawai and pilihan. PK pegawai = nokom, pilihan = kdpilih. For now, the data on pegawai table contain 3 data/rows, but why doesn't show anything? If the data show correctly, will it show only the name and not numbers?

Tables:

pegawai: nokom, nip, nama, jk, agama

pilihan: kdpilih, nmpilih

jk and agama contain numbers from kdpilih on pilihan table, here is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
   <table class="table table-striped">
     <tr>
       <th align="center" scope="col">NOKOM</th>
       <th align="center" scope="col">NIP</th>
       <th align="center" scope="col">NAMA</th>
       <th align="center" scope="col">JK</th>
       <th align="center" scope="col">AGAMA</th>
       <th align="center" scope="col">Aksi</th>
     </tr>

<?php
  require "config.php";
  $sql    = "SELECT * FROM pegawai INNER JOIN pilihan ON pilihan.kdpilih = pegawai.nokom ORDER BY nip ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr class=\"table table-striped\">
              <td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">".$data['nokom']."</td>
              <td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">".$data['nip']."</td>
              <td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">".$data['nama']."</td>
              <td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">".$data['jk']."</td>
              <td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">".$data['agama']."</td>
              <td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\">
                <a href=\"pegawai_ubah.php?id=$data[id]\">Ubah</a>  
                <a href=\"pegawai_hapus.php?id=$data[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Apakah Anda yakin?');\">Hapus</a>
              </td>
            </tr>";
    }
  }
    else
    {
      echo "Belum ada data.";
    }
?>

  </table>
</div>
```

any help will be so thankful. Thanks

Comment: `nip` from which table?

Comment: @Faradox pegawai table

Comment: try this: `"SELECT * FROM pegawai p LEFT JOIN pilihan ph ON ph.kdpilih = p.nokom ORDER BY p.nip ASC"`. and make sure that ph.kdpilih = p.nokom the same datas

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` put this and check exact error what is hapening

Comment: where is your connection `mysqli_connect`

Comment: @AzmiColeJr did you tried what i said?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh still doesn't show anything sir.

Comment: print your query and then run it manually in your sql and check any record is coming or not?

Comment: @Faradox i try "SELECT * FROM pegawai p LEFT JOIN pilihan ph ON ph.kdpilih = p.nokom ORDER BY p.nip ASC" but jk and agama show numbers. jk on pegawai table will contain 50001, 50002, and 50003 which mean on pilihan table: 50001 = man, 50002 = woman, 50003 = etc. So, i want jk and agama will show man/woman/etc according what the numbers set on pegawai table. sorry if my words complicated.

Comment: @Faradox my mysqli_connect is on config.php file, when i try 1 table it shows the data, so in my opinion the mysqli_connect will no error

Comment: @anantkumarsingh the data show successfully but jk still showing numbers, how if make it into word like man/ woman/ etc ?

Answer (score 0):

finally works, i did:

$sql = "SELECT a.nokom, a.nip, a.nama, a.agama, b.nmpilih AS jk, c.nmpilih as agama FROM pegawai a JOIN pilihan b ON 
          b.kdpilih = a.jk JOIN pilihan c ON c.kdpilih = a.agama ORDER BY a.nip ASC";